# Grub problem with Windows 8

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows, windows-8

I had Ubuntu 12.10 and Win7 in dual-boot. I made the update for Win8, and the Grub was ok. I just loggedin on Ubuntu and made an update in grub with Grub Edit (decrease the waiting time for 2 seconds). After that, the grub show, but I can't select what entry I want.

The problem is that Win8 is the default, so I can't enter on Ubuntu to edit the grub.

Any idea what's can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Recommended Repair` of the tool called Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair